# MetadataDisplayer.with_model_file causes unpack buffer error

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite

I have tried to use this code

```
displayer = _metadata.MetadataDisplayer.with_model_file(path)
export_json_file = os.path.join(os.path.splitext(model_path)[0] + ".json")
json_file = displayer.get_metadata_json()
with open(export_json_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(json_file)
```

to load metadata of a tflite model, but this line

```
displayer = _metadata.MetadataDisplayer.with_model_file(model_path)
```

raises the following error

```
unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 32 bytes for unpacking 4 bytes at offset 28 (actual buffer size is 21)
```

How this should be fixed?